# Obtaining data-pids using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape the following website using Beautiful Soup in Python 3.

https://www.pgatour.com/competition/2017/safeway-open/leaderboard.html

Each player has a data-pid number associated, and the xpath looks like so:

[image: Xpaths for the Players]

As the class is not constant, and changes with each player, I am having trouble extracting the div.

I have tried to use this after parsing the html, but without luck.

`soup.find_all('div',{'class','leaderboard-item'})`

Essentially, the output should simply be a list of the numbers within the data-pids. Would very much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use requests lib

```
import requests
json = requests.get('https://statdata.pgatour.com/r/464/2017/player_stats.json').json()
pids = [player['pid'] for player in json['tournament']['players']]
```

I can't find a solution how can I parse it using Beautiful soup. Above link to json I've found using chrome developer tools in tab Network.

Comment: Thanks Rafal, that worked brilliantly. Didn't know about the Network tab in chrome...should be very useful!